# Pip install pandas: installing dependencies error

Tags: python, pandas, virtualenv

I am trying to `pip install pandas` in a virtual environment but I am having an error I really do not understand.

[image: pandas error]

I am guessing it has something to do with the `Double requirement given` but I really do not know where to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I met the same error on Python3.4.

And the root cause of this error is that

> "pandas 0.21-0.22 no longer supports Python 3.4"

**See more about this issue:**

> https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20775
>
> **Problem with installing pandas for Python 3.4**
>
> You get the error "Double requirement given: numpy ..."
>   The reason for this error is that pandas 0.21-0.22 no longer supports Python 3.4, and thus no longer distributes binary wheels for Python 3.4. Therefore, pip tries to install pandas from source, and this is what now started to fail with Pip version 10.
>   You can check your python version.

```sh
$ python --version
Python 3.4.3
```

**[Solution: Install python 3.5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get)**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

After you install python 3.5, you can install pandas successfully in a virtual environment(with Python 3.5).

Comment: For me I was getting this issue because I was using Python 3.7 and Pandas 0.22.0 only supports up to Python 3.6.  I installed Pandas 0.24.2 which supports Python 3.7 and it installed successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a clean & fresh new venv? If not, one thing to try is making a new venv, then first installing numpy and after that pandas.

BTW: I'd suggest switching to Python 3.

Comment: tried your answer but replicates the same error above.

Answer (score 2):

the latest version of pandas have some issue with python3.4, if you have python3.4 you can install 0.20.3 version of pandas
pip3 install pandas==0.20.3

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install via pip, you can install via your system's repositories see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#installing-using-your-linux-distribution-s-package-manager).

Comment: I would need to run in a virtual python environment hence the use of `pip` since this is a central system and I do not have enough privileges to modify/install.